# Keras Inception-v3 fine-tuning workaraound

Tags: performance, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to fine-tune Inception-v3, but no matter which layer I choose to freeze I get random predictions. I found that other people are having the same problem: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9214 . It seems that the problem comes from setting the BN layer to not trainable. 
Now I am trying to get the output of the last layer I want to freeze and use it as an input to the following layers, which I will then train:

```python
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                os.path.join(directory, "train_data"),
                target_size=size,
                interpolation="bilinear",
                classes=["a", "b", "c","d"],
                batch_size=1,
                shuffle=False) base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=True, input_shape=(299, 299, 3))

model_features = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer(
                self.Inception_Fine_Tune_Layers[layer_freeze]).output)

#I want to use this as input 
values_train = model_features.predict_generator(train_generator, verbose=1)
```

However, I get Memory error like this, although I have 12Gb, which is more than what I need:

```python
....
 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 3268864 totalling 3.12MiB
 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 3489024 totalling 3.33MiB
 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 4211968 totalling 4.02MiB
 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 5129472 totalling 4.89MiB
 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:700] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 3.62GiB
 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:702] Stats: 
Limit:                 68719476736
InUse:                  3886957312
MaxInUse:               3889054464
NumAllocs:                    3709
MaxAllocSize:              8388608
```

Any suggestion how to fix that or another workaround to fine-tune Inception will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you're preprocessing your input properly from what you've provided. However, Keras provides functions for preprocessing that are specific to the pre-trained net, in this case Inception V3.

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
```

Try adding this to your data generator as the preprocessing function like so...

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            os.path.join(directory, "train_data"),
            preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,  # <---
            target_size=size,
            interpolation="bilinear",
            classes=["a", "b", "c","d"],
            batch_size=1,
            shuffle=False)
```

You should then be able to unfreeze all of the layers, or the select few that you want to train.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am already using the correct preprocessing: 
        train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(data_format='channels_last', preprocessing_function=preprocess_inception)
I already fine-tuned VGG-19 and it worked normal. The problem is that by calling layer.istrainable = False on BN layer (which is present in Inception-v3) some variables keep updating or at least that is the assumption. If I fine-tune all layers in Inception-v3 there is no problem - validation accuracy increases, but when I freeze layers validation accuracy stays the same

Comment: Can you provide the code that you're using to freeze the layers?